# Associativity of the Dirichlet Convolution Product

Tags: arithmetic-functions, associativity, dirichlet-convolution

How can you prove that the convolution product of arithmetical functions is associative and that it is distributive with respect to the addition?

The book that I am reading states that $(F_a, *)$ is a commutative monoid, where $F_a$ is the set of all arithmetic functions, that is: $f: N^* \rightarrow C,$ and * is the Dirichlet product of convolution, that is: $(f*g)(n)=$the sum of all $f(d)g(n/d)$ taken for all the divisors "$d$" of $n.$

An edit with mathematical expressions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the same way that the normal convolution is associative and commutative and distributive over the addition : for example because under the Fourier (Laplace) transform it becomes a multiplication : $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s})(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a\ast b)_n n^{-s}$ where $a \ast b$ is the Dirichlet convolution.

Comment: note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ is also the Laplace transform of the distribution $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta(t-\ln n)$, and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a\ast b)_n \delta(t-\ln n)$ is also the normal convolution of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \delta(t-\ln n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \delta(t-\ln n)$

Comment: There is nothing more elementary than that? I am not familiar with Laplace transformations, I'm affraid

Comment: that $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s})(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a\ast b)_n n^{-s}$ where $(a \ast b)_n = \sum_{d | n} a_d b_{n/d}$ is enough to prove that the Dirichlet convolution has the same properties as a multiplication : the left-hand side is a multiplication...

Comment: yes ? convinced ? clearly $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n^{-s}) = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}) \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n^{-s}) $$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} (\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n^{-s}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n n^{-s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n n^{-s}$$